# A macro which is similiar to \prescript but it can be used in text mode

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

How to define a macro, say `\pretextsuperscript`, to get a presuperscript ahead a word in text mode?

Just simply write `\textsuperscript{2}hormone` and `\textsuperscript{2}population` is incorrect. Why say that you can see from

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\prescript{2}{}{h}$ $\prescript{2}{}{p}$
\end{document}
```

The prescript (in former sample is "2") should be vertically adjusted with the first letter of the argument of prescript. Also, the prescript should be upshape. I found the `\prescript` can only be used in math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Text mode

If you want a `\textpresuperscript` to be used in text mode, then

```
\newcommand{\textpresuperscript}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{#1}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

will give you the possibility to write

```
\textpresuperscript{2}longword
```

with the result that "longword" can be hyphenated, but there will be no break between the superscript and the (first segment of the) following word. Here's an example:

```
\parbox{4cm}{What's \textpresuperscript{2}supercalifragilisticexpialidocious?}
```

produces

---

[image]

---

## Math mode

If one needs to put a word in the presuperscript, then (`mathtools` is required)

```
$\prescript{\text{word}}{}h$
```

should be the solution. If the word should be in upright shape independent of the context outside the formula, then

```
$\prescript{\text{\normalfont word}}{}h$
```

will do. Of course one can define one's own macro:

```
\newcommand{\pretextsuperscript}[1]{\prescript{\text{#1}}{}}
```

(possibly adding `\normalfont`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a shortcoming in your solution: the word with superscript cannot automatically be hyphenated because the `\text` is basically a hbox.

Comment: You can't have hyphenation in superscripts; the only way would be using an "all-superscript-font". Moreover, text in math mode is *never* hyphenated. What's precisely your problem?

Comment: I want the letter "h" (almost a word for notation, like \pretextsuperscript{2}{notation}) in upshape and can have hyphenation. If I place the all thing in math environment, I think I have to put "notation" in a box.

Comment: Please, edit your message to show your needs more clearly: where's the "h" in your last comment?

Comment: Okey. By the way, "h" is in your solution too.

Comment: Your question is *very* hard to understand. Please, look at my edited answer and try to clarify your question stating explicitly that math mode *isn't* involved.

Comment: hi, I think `\textsuperscript{2}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}longword` could not be **vertically adjusted with the first letter** of longword.

Comment: I insist: what do you need *precisely* and for what purpose? With this macro all presuperscripts will be at the same height and I wouldn't adjust them depending on the first letter of the following word.